Add a fee in WooCommerce checkout based on the chosen shipping method, payment method and postcode
I want to add an extra charge when the customer chooses geniki taxydromiki as the shipping method and pays cash on delivery or by card or bank deposit and if the customer belongs to specific zip codes. i use this snippet. what is wrong
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_extra_charge_for_specific_conditions');

function add_extra_charge_for_specific_conditions() {
    // Define the shipping method, payment methods, and zip codes for the extra charge
    $shipping_method_id = array('8', '9'); // Replace with the actual shipping method ID
    $payment_methods = array('cod', 'alphabank_gateway', 'bacs'); // Replace with the actual payment method IDs
    $target_zip_codes = array('49100', '29300', '10003'); // Replace with the actual zip codes

    // Get the chosen shipping method
    $chosen_shipping_methods = WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods');
    $chosen_shipping_method = $chosen_shipping_methods[0];

    // Get the chosen payment method
    $chosen_payment_method = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method');

    // Get the customer's zip code
    $customer_zip_code = WC()->customer->get_billing_postcode();

    // Check if the conditions are met
    if ($chosen_shipping_method === $shipping_method_id &&
        in_array($chosen_payment_method, $payment_methods) &&
        in_array($customer_zip_code, $target_zip_codes)) {
        
        // Define the extra charge
        $extra_charge = 5.00; // Set the extra charge amount

        // Add the extra charge
        WC()->cart->add_fee(__('Extra Charge for Geniki Taxydromiki', 'text-domain'), $extra_charge);
    }
}

I want to add an extra fee in checkout page.

Edit:
the rate id for my shipping method is flat_rate:8 when the customer pay cash on delivery, and free_shipping:9 when the customer has free shipping with the same courier when an order amount is over 15€

Update:
There are some mistakes in your code and you need to define the correct shipping rate Ids (see at the end how).
You can use the following code replacement:
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_checkout_extra_charge_conditionally');
function add_checkout_extra_charge_conditionally( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Define below the shipping method rate IDs, payment methods IDs, and zip codes:
    $shipping_rates_ids  = array('free_shipping:9', 'flat_rate:8');
    $payment_methods_ids = array('cod', 'bacs', 'alphabank_gateway'); // payment method IDs
    $allowed_zip_codes   = array('49100', '29300', '10003'); // Allowed zip codes

    $chosen_shipping_methods = WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods'); // Get the chosen shipping method
    $chosen_payment_method   = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method'); // Get the chosen payment method
    $shipping_zip_code       = WC()->customer->get_billing_postcode(); // Get customer shipping zip code

    // Check if the conditions are met
    if ( in_array( current($chosen_shipping_methods), $shipping_rates_ids)
        && in_array($chosen_payment_method, $payment_methods_ids)
        && in_array($shipping_zip_code, $allowed_zip_codes) ) 
    {
        $extra_charge = 5.00; // Set the extra charge amount

        // Add the extra charge
        $cart->add_fee( __('Extra Charge for Geniki Taxydromiki', 'woocommerce'), $extra_charge );
    }
}

// Update checkout on payment method change (jQuery)
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_init', 'trigger_update_checkout_on_payment_method_change' );
function trigger_update_checkout_on_payment_method_change(){
    wc_enqueue_js("$('form.checkout').on( 'change', 'input[name=payment_method]', function(){
        $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
    });");
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and work.

To get the correct shipping Method rate IDs to be used in your code, you can use temporarily the following function that will display in the footer, the list of current shipping methods with their Rate ID:
add_action('wp_footer', 'get_shipping_method_rate_ids');
function get_shipping_method_rate_ids() {
    $output = '';

    foreach ( array_keys( (array) WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages() ) as $key ) {
        $shipping_for_package = WC()->session->get('shipping_for_package_'.$key);

        if( isset($shipping_for_package['rates']) ) {
            foreach ( $shipping_for_package['rates'] as $rate ) {
                $output .= '<tr><td>'. $rate->get_label() . '</td><td><code><small>' . $rate->get_id() . '</small></code></td></tr>';
            }
        }
    }
    
    if ( ! empty($output) ) {
        echo '<div style="padding:25px 50px;"><h3>Get shipping method rate IDs</h3>
        <table style="max-width:600px;"><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Rate ID</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>' . $output . '</tbody></table></pre>';
    }
}

Once you get the correct shipping rates IDs, you can remove the code function.

I took out the line of code you said and I put the other 2 lines exactly but it doesn't work

because i am not developer i don't understand what should I do.. Dare I ask you for more help?Thank you very much for your time, but I don't understand

I have to do something? I don't understand
